# Redis Recursion: Maximum callstack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, redis, node-redis

I am trying to write a timer for a game. I decided to use Redis and Web Sockets to keep the timer consistent across multiple devices. I have a function that works however when I go to call it recursively with either setTimeout or setInterval I get a "Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded". I can not figure out how to bypass this error. Does anyone know if it has to do with the blocking nature of the node-redis publish method? I have attached the code below.

```
const tick = (time: Time, publisher: RedisClient) => {
  let newTime: Time = { minutes: 0, seconds: 0}
  if(time.seconds === 0) {
    if(time.minutes === 0) {
      newTime = {minutes: 4, seconds: 0}
    } else {
      newTime = {minutes: time.minutes - 1, seconds: 59}
    }
  } else {
    newTime = {...time, seconds: time.seconds - 1}
  }
  let ticker = setInterval(tick(newTime, publisher), 1000)
  publisher.publish("scoring:timer", `${newTime.minutes}: ${newTime.seconds}`)
  publisher.on("message", function(_chanel, message) {
     if(message === "STOP") {
       clearInterval(ticker)
     }
  })
}

function startTimer() {
  const publisher = createClient()
  publisher.publish("scoring:events", "START")
  let time = { 
    minutes: 4,
    seconds: 0
  }
  tick(time, publisher)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing `tick()` before setting an interval which results in an infinite loop:

```js
setInterval(tick(newTime, publisher), 1000);
```

You should provide a function that will be executed by the `setInterval()` itself:

```js
setInterval(() => tick(newTime, publisher), 1000);
```

PS: The current implementation as is, should be using `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` because your `setInterval()` executes its callback every second (and your callback sets another timer, which executes a callback that sets another timer, which executs a .... do you see another loop there?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That solution did work however I ended up just storing the time values in Redis so I did not have to pass any arguments to tick.